# C# XmlSerializer de-serialize abstract class without knowing concrete class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I would like to deserialize xml where the root class is an Abstract class but the root node in the xml has a value of the XML root attribute in the concrete class. The key is to do this without specifying the concrete class to deserialize in the `XmlSerializer` constructor.

Example:

MessageType.cs

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Entity))]
public abstract class MessageType
{
}
```

Entity.cs

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Entity", IsNullable = false)]
public class Entity : MessageType
{
    private string data;

    public string Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var entity = new Entity
{
    Data = "test"
};

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Entity));

using var stream = new System.IO.StringWriter();

xs.Serialize(stream, entity);
var xml = stream.ToString();

using var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);

xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageType));
var obj = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
```

This code results in

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: <Entity xmlns=''> was not expected.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMessageType.Read4_MessageType()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
```

The xml produced by the serialization in the code above looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Entity xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Data>test</Data>
</Entity>
```

Couple Extra Notes:

1. In the real case, the xml message comes from another application that I have 0 control
   over.
2. The c# classes come from an XSD so I'm unable to change those either
3. There are a lot of concrete class implementations of the `MessageType` class and
   with xml deserialization seeming to be a slow process, looping over each possible type
   and seeing if it can deserialize is not ideal
4. I know there are a lot of similar questions on stackoverflow but have been unable to
   find one that answers my exact question
5. I understand if the received xml looked like

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
   <MessageType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="Entity">
       <Data>test</Data>
   </MessageType>
   ```

   that it would work, but refer to note #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the name of the root node with the XmlReader. Then you can get the type by name and create the serializer accordingly.

```
using var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
xmlReader.MoveToContent();
var rootNodeName = xmlReader.Name;

var implementationType = Type.GetType(rootNodeName);
if (implementationType != null)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(implementationType);
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
else
{
    // unknown type
}
```

Comment: That would only work if the root node matches the class name which in my case it does not. Sounds like I need to talk to the people sending the message and try and get them to send the base class as the root with the type as an attribute.

Comment: @GarrettHines my answer was to get you started with the information you provided, without an actual file it is difficult to know all of the requirements. That said the XmlReader is powerfull and it should be easy to navigate to descendants or siblings until you find what you need.